# How to install a header-only (odeint) library in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++, odeint

I am using g++ 4.4 under Debian Sqeeze and I have boost installed. I am able to run a simple boost matrix [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm#12Example) with headers:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
```

But I'd like to add also `odeint` header:

```
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>
```

However, it is not possible as my /usr/include/boost/numeric folder lists only

```
conversion  interval  interval.hpp  ublas
```

How to install odeint?

`odeint` is a header-only library, no linking against pre-compiled code is required. I've downloaded [.tar](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/downloads.html) and copied `odeint` folder and `odeint.hpp` file to my /usr/include/boost/numeric folder. However, it does not work. On compilation I get error:

```
error: boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp: No such file
```

Comment: Do you have boost::range installed? It's finding the odeint headers just fine, but one of them includes headers from the range library that aren't there.

Comment: @deong: Thanx, boost/range/algorithm was missing. Likely because I installed boost as a debian packaged instead of [boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html). Now I installed boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2 and everything works as odeint is included in this distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed my boost library installed through

```
apt-get install libboost1.42-dev
```

which does not contained `odeint`. Then I installed [boost_1_54_0.tar.bz2.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html), which already contains odeint. Now I can run odeint programs, e.g. [this](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html).

Comment: Now you probably have 2 versions, and if you unintentionally mix them, you have high chances to get ODR violations.

Comment: @Igor R. I've removed old boost directory from /usr/include/. Is it not enough to remove the old 1.42 boost version?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I misunderstood you. If you completely removed both the headers and the binaries, then it's ok. Actually, it's also pretty legitimate to have multiple Boost versions, but then you should make sure you never mix them.