# Compiler errors: Installing odeint properly

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the package odeint working. I am on ubuntu using g++.

I found this question:
[How to install a header-only (odeint) library in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300059/how-to-install-a-header-only-odeint-library-in-linux/18300971#18300971)

I downloaded the boost libraries that include odeint, and extract the boost map to /usr/include. When I compile any of the examples on the odeinit website, I get a huge list of errors. What am I doing wrong?

There was no boost map previously present in /usr/include, and as far as I know, boost wasn't installed.

Comment: Can you show us some errors? Odeint is included in boost since version 1.53. If you download a recent version you can use it without installing odeint.

Comment: I found a fix. Added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing the odeint folder and odeint.hpp file from the boost installation and replacing them with those from the odeint page.

Comment: You can also leave the odeint folder in the boost directory and specify the location of the github odeint version in the include path before the include path for boost.